# "at lunch break" vs "in lunch break"

Tags: prepositions

> I read books at lunch break.
>
> I read books in lunch break.

Are either of these sentences incorrect? "At" sounds a little more natural to my ears but I don't know why.

To give some more context here, I'm referring to the lunch break period at school.

Though I've seen previous threads about this over at English Stack Exchange, none of them have provided satisfactory answers

Comment: I like _during_ better than _at_ or _in_.

Comment: I agree, but would "in" or "at" be incorrect?

Comment: Prepositions are very flexible. There are often blurry lines between idiomatic, awkward, and incorrect.

Comment: The best choice is _"I read books at lunch break"._ _"In"_ is not idiomatic with _lunch break,_ any more that we would describe books as being _in a shelf._ The idiom is firmly _"at/on [my] lunch break"_,  but not _"in lunch break."_ The terms _correct_ and _incorrect_ do not apply here.

Comment: Funny, but I think it's more idiomatic to say ***on*** lunch break. It's what I've been saying for decades. I may be "at lunch" but "on lunch break" ...

Comment: "on *my* lunch break"

Comment: @Robusto Aye, _at/on_ but never _in._ (The OP doesn't offer _on._) I've heard (and said) _"I'll see you at [my] lunch break"_ myself.

Answer (score 1):

The sample sentence is actually quite ambiguously constructed. "Lunch break" is such a vague term, that makes it difficult for one to determine the "correct answer" in this scenario.

"At" is more frequently used in a spatial sense, though it also can be used in a time sense. It is used to convey a sense of precision. Since we are describing both location and time, "at" appears to be an acceptable option. However, the sentence feels "off", probably due to the ambiguous message "at" sends. Is the author emphasizing on the timing or the location of the event (lunch break) to describe the action (read books)?

"In" is more related to a spatial description, but can also be used to describe time if applied towards a specific time period (e.g. This happened in the Cold War era). Given that "lunch break" is not a specific time period, and there is nothing that give hints to where the location of this event is actually within some enclosure, "in" is not a very proper way to construct this sentence.

Some suggested "on" as well in the comments, which is related to the phrase "on break". However, "on" faces the same problem as "at" and "in" in that it can be used to describe both the time element and the space element of something. It also creates confusion with the way the sentence is constructed. (e.g. I read some books on the floor - is the message clear here? Grammatically, yes it refers to "I", but it is not a very clear way to construct the sentence.) Though it is true that the sentence can only be logically interpreted as "on break", "on" nonetheless is not a good choice here because of the ambiguity it creates. To use "on" to construct the sentence, you should clarify this ambiguity. (e.g. I read some books while I was on lunch break).

Some suggested "during", which can only be used to describe time. Since ninjas do not exist in this world, "during" is actually the best option because it does not give ambiguous messages on whether the preposition is describing time or place. "I read some books during lunch break" automatically means that you are focusing on the time element of the lunch break, and it is understood that you are at wherever you are at during the lunch break when you say so. The clarity makes this the most preferable option of all.

Comment: If we consider "lunch break" to be a set one hour period, like at school, would  "in" still be improper?

Comment: "In" is generally used for a specific time period, where there is an understanding of a clear beginning and end of the period. I am planning to read some books in the afternoon (between noon and evening). I am planning to read some books in the fifth period (fifth period is after the fourth and before the sixth period). To make lunch period a specific time period, you will need "from" and "to". By that time, you probably won't need to use "in" anymore.

Comment: Why can a lunch period not be from 12 to 13? Wouldn't it be a specific period?

Comment: Yes, a lunch break can be from 12-13. But that will still not work because the phrase "lunch break" does not have a well accepted definition of when it starts or end - it's arbitary. Whereas, things like "afternoon" or "the fifth period" has well defined limits intrinsically.

Answer (score 0):

I read books in lunch break is correct. At is time of preposition usually refer to specific point of time nor duration of time.

You can use both of sentences which are below:

> I read books in lunch break.
>
> I read books during lunch break.

Moreover, You can use at in different sense.

> I will talk to you at lunch.

Comment: No, "in lunch break" in incorrect. It is not something native speakers would say.